# Pros/cons of a global observer object vs. a mixin

Tags: javascript, design-patterns, backbone.js, observer-pattern, publish-subscribe

When creating a complex JS application, what are the pros and cons of using a global observer object which fires events and which all other objects subscribe to vs. mixing in or prototyping pub/sub methods on all objects which are responsible for triggering their own events?

Take for example a card game which has dealer, player, and table objects (psuedocode-ish follows):

```
// "Global" observer version

var observer = {
    // publish and subscribe methods defined here
};

dealer.deal = function(cards) {
    // performs logic for dealing cards
    observer.publish('dealer:dealt', cards, this);
};

player.play = function(cards) {
    // performs logic for which card is played
    observer.publish('player:played', cards, this);
};

table.showCards = function(cards, player) {
    // performs logic for showing cards that the dealer dealt
    // or that the player played
};

observer.subscribe('dealer:dealt', table.showCards);
observer.subscribe('player:played', table.showCards);
```

vs

```
// Pub/sub mixin/prototype version

dealer.deal = function(cards) {
    // performs logic for dealing cards
    this.publish('dealt', cards);
};

player.play = function(cards) {
    // performs logic for which card is played
    this.publish('played', cards);
};

table.showCards = function(cards) {
    // performs logic for showing cards that the dealer dealt
    // or that the player played
};

dealer.subscribe('dealt', table.showCards);
player.subscribe('played', table.showCards);
```

Comment: Which way did you end up going? I'm currently grappling with the same decision. And even a year after you posed the question there seems to be no clear data out there to help make the choice. Global even pools seem more freeing and less memory intensive, but when systems start getting really huge I wonder if it will just become unmanageably complex.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your examples both seem a valid choice, but the difference can be seen when dealing with dynamic event names (also dynamic 'publisher' names).

So using a global emitter is good when you need to subscribe to events using a wildcard. Example:

```
eventEmitter.subscribe('*:delt', handler);
```

Another difference is that you can have one variable instead of 2,3 ... N, which is better for memory I believe.

Comment: I was hoping for a more thorough answer with a list of pros/cons and some possible performance data to back it up, but since no one else answered, you get the check since you provided some useful feedback. Thanks!